# How to set subdomain on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have an app which have multiple sub domains and work locally fine.

```
manager.daycare.no:3000/
worker.daycare.no:3000/
daycare.no:3000/
admin.daycare.no:3000/
parent.daycare.no:3000/
```

When I deploy it on heroku these sub-domains doesn't work.
Heroku app url is `https://polar-harbor-19809.herokuapp.com/` .

How I set these subdomains on heroku and please tell me what will be url after subdomain urls?

Answer (score 1):

Subdomains are only available with a custom domain, not with a herokuapp.com domain!

Comment: You mean I buy domain first?

Comment: KIndly ellaborate it please

Comment: Yes, you need a custom domain! See their documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)